# Multiple Visual Studio files in the same window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tabs

Whenever I open up a Visual Studio file from within the Unity window it opens each file in a separate window, as opposed to being separate tabs in the same window. How would I fix this?

Comment: Let me be see if I understand you correctly, you double-click on a c# script in Unity editor and a instance of VS opens. And the problem is that when you click on another script, a whole new VS window opens?

Comment: Yes, it opens an entirely new window every time.

Comment: Please, open the Solution Explorer in one of instances of Visual Studio, do you see there the complete hierarchy of scripts that you have in project or there is only one file? (also, make sure, its VS, not VS code)

Comment: It says "Solution 'Solution1' (0 projects)"

Answer (score 1):

Apparently its a common problem on [unity forums](https://forum.unity.com/) (you can check them: [1](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1078859/unity-keeps-opening-new-instances-of-microsoft-vis.html), [2](https://forum.unity.com/threads/why-does-each-c-script-open-in-a-new-separate-instance-of-visual-studio.455104/), [3](https://answers.unity.com/questions/628248/visual-studio-opens-new-instances-on-every-click.html))

**The problem** appears to be related to updatinng the project to a new version of Unity

**The solution** is to delete the .csproj files and the .sln file for the project. Unity  will just recreate them immediately, and the files will correctly open in the same instance of VS.

Answer (score 1):

For me only this solution worked (from [This Thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/why-does-each-c-script-open-in-a-new-separate-instance-of-visual-studio.455104/))

I just removed Visual Studio Editor package from Package Manager, and the problem looks like fixed now

Answer (score 0):

*---Edited by answerer - this solution is for Visual Studio Code, and not Visual Studio. It does not answer @AlphaWolf464's question correctly.---*

This might be due to the settings set in the preferences.
Follow the directions below to change these settings (below is for Mac, so it may look a bit different for Windows)

Open Visual Studio and navigate to **Code** --> **Preferences** --> **Settings**

[image: Screenshot of navigating to the Settings menu on Visual Studio]

From the left options, navigate to **Window** --> **New Window**

If the **Open Folders In New Window** option is set to *on*, change this to *off*.

[image: Screenshot of navigating to the Open Folders In New Window option on Visual Studio]

Comment: He pointed out that its Visual Studio, not Visual Studio code

Comment: Thank you @ValeriuSeremet , I missed that completely. I've updated my answer to state that this is the wrong solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, I believe it was related to upgrading a project to a new version of unity. I resolved it by deleting the .csproj files and the .sln file for the project. Unity just recreated them immediately, and the files correctly opened in the same instance of VS.